# Skype issue : not getting my voice back while testing with echo calling

Tags: 14.04, skype, microphone

I have issue with Skype. It's not getting my voice back while testing with echo calling.

Comment: Have you checked that your mic is working correct? I had issues the first time and it was down to a dodge mic. It woyld also be worth checking your speaker volume just to help rule out the basics first. Before going deeper.

Comment: did you check the mic with some other program?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if these will work but..

1) In a terminal type `alsamixer`
check all volumes for Mic's are up

2) Look at pulse audio volume control `pavucontrol`- see if you are getting a signal when calling Echo - and check that you are using **duplex** configuration.

There is a setting in skype which lets skype alter volume - its a good idea to try that.